# Calling getView in fragment returns null

Tags: android, view, dialog, null, fragment

I'm really having hard time and im desperate to find a solution for this:

I'm using ABS library for fragments in my application.

This is the `onCreateView` method in my fragment class:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details_fragment, container, false);

    prefs = getSherlockActivity().getSharedPreferences(prefName, getSherlockActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);

    day = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString(BIRTH_KEY, "").substring(0, 2));
    month = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString(BIRTH_KEY, "").substring(3, 5));
    year = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString(BIRTH_KEY, "").substring(6, 10));

    name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.nameEdit);
    age  = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ageEdit);


    name.setText(prefs.getString(FIRST_NAME_KEY, "") + " " + prefs.getString(LAST_NAME_KEY, ""));
    age.setText(getAge(year, month, day) + " years");

    age.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showDatePickerDialog();

        }
    });
    return view;
}

public void update() {
    System.out.println(getView());
}
```

This DateDialogPicker class:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends SherlockDialogFragment implements OnDateSetListener {

private SharedPreferences prefs;
private String prefName = "UserPref";
private static final String BIRTH_KEY = "date_of_birth";

private Date dateObj;
private FragmentDetails frag;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    prefs = getSherlockActivity().getSharedPreferences(prefName, getSherlockActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);

    frag = new FragmentDetails();

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int day = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString(BIRTH_KEY, "").substring(0, 2));
    int month = (Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString(BIRTH_KEY, "").substring(3, 5))-1);
    int year = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString(BIRTH_KEY, "").substring(6, 10));

    return new DatePickerDialog(getSherlockActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
        int dayOfMonth) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String _date = (dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear+1) + "/" + year);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    editor.putString(BIRTH_KEY, formatDate(_date));
    editor.commit();

    FragmentDetails frag = new FragmentDetails();
    frag.update();

}   

private String formatDate(String date) {
    SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
    try {
        dateObj = curFormater.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return (curFormater.format(dateObj));
}
}
```

Everything works fine. But I want to update textview of fragment on Date set, by calling update method of FragmentDetails class in `onDateSet` method. But accessing textview using view or method `getView()` returns *null pointer exeption*.

In this case method `update()` prints `getView()` and its result is null.

How can i get the View of the fragment so I can access and manage textviews of this view.

**EDIT**

So far i found out that i can access any view of fragment while im in the fragment instance but when i create a new dialog i cant `getView` of that fragment from dialog instance.

Comment: Have you tried moving the date code into `onViewCreated`? The `View` should exist at this point, while there's no guarantee of it existing in `onCreateView`.

Comment: well, when i try to log that view in onViewCreated() it returns android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout@413e9228, so the view exists at this point, but i tried to save it in variable and then again it return null.

Comment: So finally i solved my problem. I can access textviews of fragment in  `DatePickerFragment` class by initializing `textview` with 
`TextView age = (TextView)getSherlockActivity().findViewById(R.id.ageEdit);`

Comment: @Eric There are not enough upvotes in the world for me to give you...

Comment: @Sherz Glad I was able to help! :D